# Wordpress rest API: How do I append all ACF of a Post Object?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api, acfpro

**Im working with the followings:**

1. Nuxt 2.15.7 for frontend development
2. Wordpress 5.8
3. CPT 1.9.2
4. Advanced Custom Fields PRO 5.9.9
5. ACF to REST API 3.3.2
6. ACF to REST API Recursive *Deactivated at this moment*.

**Situation:**

I have two CPTs Hiking Routes and Landmarks, both of them have Custom Fields. In CPT Landmark, Im trying to pull data from Hiking Route as post object, so I can show the details such as Route length and Route colour which are custom fields. But unfortunately, I was only able to get the generic post data without any custom fields.
Note: Im using nuxt to build the frontend so Im trying to get the result in rest api.

I have tried various solutions with and without ACF to REST API Recursive plugin. A very resourceful thread is here
https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api/issues/109

I would really appreciate if anyone explains exactly how I can achieve this.

Thank you in advance.

Note: If you think question can be improved, please do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if i understand what your looking for i came across this issue a while ago and added something along these lines, you may need to mod this but add to functions file

```
add_filter( 'acf/rest_api/{post_type}/get_fields', function( $data ) {
  if ( ! empty( $data ) ) {
     array_walk_recursive( $data, 'get_fields_recursive' );
  }

  return $data;
} );

function get_fields_recursive( $item ) {
    if ( is_object( $item ) ) {
        $item->acf = array();
        if ( $fields = get_fields( $item ) ) {
            $item->acf = $fields;                   
            array_walk_recursive( $item->acf, 'get_fields_recursive' );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `if ( ! empty( $data ) ) {` is unnecessary, right?